# python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory (Docker-compose)

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

when i tryna run a django server with docker-compose up, i got this error

```
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Network service_default      Created                                                                                                                                                                0.3s 
 ✔ Container service-web-app-1  Created                                                                                                                                                                0.5s 
Attaching to service-web-app-1
service-web-app-1  | python3: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
service-web-app-1 exited with code 2
```

My docker-compose

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  # postgres:
  #   image: postgres:15 
  #   container_name: dj_post
  #   env_file:
  #     - .env
  web-app:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      context: . 
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    
    command: >
      sh -c "python3 manage.py runserver "
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine3.16


COPY requirements.txt /temp/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /service

EXPOSE 8000

RUN pip install -r /temp/requirements.txt

RUN adduser --disabled-password service-user 

USER service-user
```

I will attach the architecture of the folders below, but I immediately say that by setting the full path to manage.py in docker-compose file I get the same error,I just started studying docker and for two days I can't find a working solution to this problem,share your ideas:(

[image]

Comment: The Dockerfile only copies one file, `requirements.txt`, into the container.  How were you expecting the other files to be copied?

Answer (score 3):

You need copy all files to the service folder

```
WORKDIR /service
COPY . .
```